# Problem with fog and lights on builded game

Tags: unity-webgl

When building for the web, such glitches with fog (and light) come out.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjC5o.png)

**Unity 2022.3.8**
Fog - **gamma, exponential**.
**Lights - all dynamic.**
3 cameras were used on the scene - (depth -1 - only the sky (only depth), 1 - all but without some particles (only depth), 2 - some particles (only depth)).
index.html - **"config['webglContextAttributes'] = {"preserveDrawingBuffer": true};"**

Can anyone suggest what could be the problem? (my english bad, sorry).